# Why can't Firefox open a link with a shell script that uses `source`?

Tags: shell-script, firefox

I am attempting to use GRC's [SQRL](https://www.grc.com/sqrl/sqrl.htm) client in Wine, using [this shell script](https://github.com/501st-alpha1/scott-script/blob/afd043158b19ba0a9779c11932e517d027b1a58f/grc-sqrl) to launch it. I have a couple helper scripts that I `source`, in order to reduce code duplication. An example of one such statement is:

```
source winesrc "grc-sqrl"
```

The `source`d script, here named `winesrc`, is in the same folder as my launcher script.

When I call my script directly and pass a URL as an argument, as in:

```
grc-sqrl sqrl://www.grc.com/sqrl?nut=1234567890abcdefghijkl
```

... it works fine. The problem comes when I try to set Firefox (technically [Iceweasel](https://superuser.com/questions/322376/how-to-install-the-real-firefox-on-debian)) to open the link. In `about:config` I set `network.protocol-handler.expose.sqrl` to `false`. I then clicked an SQRL link, and in the dialog that opened, selected my script.

However, whenever I clicked a SQRL link after that, nothing happened. After some trial-and-error, I managed to narrow down the problem to my `source` statements. If I remove those (and copy the relevant pieces of code directly into my script), it works fine. I also tried changing the `source` statements to `.`, but that didn't help either.

Why can't Firefox handle `source` statements in the shell scripts it launches?

Comment: Can you show one of the `source` statements? (which should be `.` by the way, because `source` is a compatibility alias and does not exist in the POSIX shell standard). Is it perchance a relative pathname, or is there a permission problem accessing the sourced script?

Comment: @Celada I don't think it is a permission problem, since the script works fine when manually run in a terminal. (The mode of the `source`d script is 644, but changing it to 755 didn't help.) As mentioned, I tried changing `source` to `.`, but that didn't help. Yes, it is a relative pathname (but the containing folder is added to my `PATH` in my `.bashrc`), so perhaps that is the problem. Edited to show example of `source` statement.